# How can I convert all jpg files to dicom with same name on matlab?

Tags: matlab, jpeg, converters, dicom

I know how to convert a jpg file to dcm with dicomwrite function but i need to convert all jpg files to dcm in a folder. Is it possible? If its possible is it possible to convert them with same name of jpg file? Thanks guys...

Comment: First of all i don't know how to do it..im beginner :) and if i add new jpg files on this folder, will your code still work too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the following:

```
folder = 'D:\test\';
file_temp = sprintf('%s\\*.jpg', folder);
filearray = dir(file_temp);
s = max(size(filearray));
for i=1: 1: s
    imgname=strcat(folder,'\\',filearray(i).name);
    I = imread(imgname);
    dicomwrite(I, [imgname '.dcm']);
end
```

It will convert all `jpg` files to `dcm` files with their original names within given `folder`.